# Videopopup.js video element play in an inner DIV and does not cover the entire screen when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, responsive

I Have put a videopopup.js on an image on the right side div container. There is another div on the left side for text matter holding. The issue is when I click on that video image, the video plays inside the DIV containing the image. I need the video object to play such that its bgcolor extends the entire screen.

I tried putting the video element's DIV alone in the whole HTML file. Then it correctly fills the entire screen. But when the video object is inside nested DIVs it plays in a smaller area.

**URL:** https://desben.org/mont/test.htm

Comment: do you want it to go fullscreen? or just bigger?

Comment: @Saymoin fullscreen is what i want

Comment: you can use `yourVideoElement.requestFullscreen()` see it on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen)

Comment: Guys i found another Html5lightbox which is very cool and solves my issues. In fact it can even open PDF files also if you want!! Thanks for your effort.